# MySQL InnoDB Spatial Index NOT working properly

Tags: mysql, innodb, geospatial

To make range comparison queries **faster**, I used **spatial index** in **MySQL & InnoDB** like below.

before:

```sql
create table 'tbl' (
   'id' BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   'min' INT NOT NULL,
   'max' INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
   KEY 'idx_range' ('min', 'max')
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

after:

```sql
create table 'tbl' (
   'id' BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   'min_max' LINESTRING NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
   SPATIAL INDEX 'idx_range' ('min_max')
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

### case 1 (spatial index in possible keys, but unused)

Insert:

```sql
INSERT INTO 'tbl'('min_max')
VALUES (LINESTRING(POINT(1, 100), POINT(1, 200))),
       (LINESTRING(POINT(1, 201), POINT(1, 300))),
       (LINESTRING(POINT(1, 301), POINT(1, 400))),
       (LINESTRING(POINT(1, 401), POINT(1, 500)));
```

Select:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(min_max, POINT(1, 150));
```

### case2 (spatial index in possible keys && used)

Insert:

```sql
INSERT INTO 'tbl'('min_max')
VALUES (LINESTRING(POINT(0, 100), POINT(1, 200))),
       (LINESTRING(POINT(0, 201), POINT(1, 300))),
       (LINESTRING(POINT(0, 301), POINT(1, 400))),
       (LINESTRING(POINT(0, 401), POINT(1, 500)));
```

Select:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE MBRTOUCHES(min_max, POINT(1, 150));
```

---

Both cases always give the same result.

I expect CASE1 to use space more efficiently than CASE2.

But it's not clear why MySQL InnoDB don't use the index in CASE1.
(In CASE1, it always scans the entire table to find the range.)

Comment: I didn't specify the version. I am using MYSQL 5.7.17.

Comment: While posting SQL codes check that they're correct.

Comment: the R tree index node in mysql seems to be skewed because there is no correct MBR for nested LineStrings. If I change it to diagonal (as in CASE2) it works fine.

Comment: 4 rows is not worth having an index.  Try a test with 1000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to specify SRID when declaring column and when adding values. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-index-optimization.html

"For comparisons to work properly, each column in a SPATIAL index must be SRID-restricted. That is, the column definition must include an explicit SRID attribute, and all column values must have the same SRID.

The optimizer considers SPATIAL indexes only for SRID-restricted columns."

Comment: thank you for answer. but, now im using mysql5.7 and there are no options for SRID